# multi-level sort and displaying details

Tags: sql, oracle

The task I have at hand is "Write a SQL Statement to find the number of sessions scheduled for each screen in every branch. Display the screen details (id of branch and screen) and their corresponding number of sessions. Perform a multi-level sort with branchid and the number of sessions."

```
SELECT SCREENID, BRANCHID
FROM SCREEN NATURAL JOIN SESSIONS;
```

**Table SCREEN:**

```
---------------------------------------
ScreenID | BranchID | Screencapacity
---------------------------------------
S1       | B1       | 120
S1       | B2       | 185
S2       | B1       | 230
S2       | B4       | 165
S2       | B3       | 185
S1       | B3       | 210
S2       | B4       | 170
S2       | B1       | 150
S3       | B2       | 135
S1       | B4       | 128
---------------------------------------
```

**Table SESSION:**

```
+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| SESSIONID | BRANCHID | SCREENID | MOVIEID | SESSIONDATE | SESSIONPRICE |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| SS01      | B1       | S1       | M1      | 03-MAY-16   |         12.5 |
| SS03      | B1       | S2       | M2      | 03-MAY-16   |        12.67 |
| SS09      | B2       | S3       | M4      | 13-MAY-16   |         17.9 |
| SS04      | B4       | S2       | M4      | 13-MAY-16   |        14.56 |
| SS07      | B4       | S2       | M3      | 14-MAY-16   |        21.78 |
| SS05      | B3       | S2       | M5      | 23-MAY-16   |        14.56 |
| SS06      | B3       | S1       | M5      | 03-JUN-16   |        16.32 |
| SS02      | B2       | S1       | M2      | 04-JUN-16   |        19.45 |
| SS10      | B4       | S1       | M3      | 06-JUN-16   |        16.37 |
| SS08      | B1       | S2       | M2      | 06-JUN-16   |        16.82 |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------------+--------------+
```

I am completely lost and am not sure where to begin on this problem

Comment: Can you please add your data in the question and don't use images?

Comment: no worries, i'll do that now

Comment: Alright it has been updated accordingly

Comment: @Dan, there is an answer to your question just waiting for your acceptance. If it helped you, click its check mark. If it did not help you, comment on how to improve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select screenid, branchid, count(1) as no_of_sessions
from screen A
    join session B
        on B.screenid = A.screenid
        and B.branchid = A.branchid
group by screenid, branchid
order by branchid, no_of_sessions
;
```

First, you join the two tables on `screenid` and `branchid`. Then, you aggregate (`group by`) the joined data to groups by `screenid` and `branchid` and simply count the number of rows in each group (`count(1)`). Then, you order the results by `branchid` and the number of sessions in the group (`no_of_sessions`).

Enjoy!